# sqlite3 INSERT INTO fails if values is a 'itertools.chain' object

Tags: python, sqlite, python-itertools

I am newbie for sqlite3 (python user)

Already stored data in database based on below method, but not working this time. INSERT INTO execuated, no error report, but nothing stored in db.

I searched this topic a lot on this website, focused on "no commit". But I am pretty sure I finished "commit" and closed file correctly.  After INSERT action, I could found table f65 in my db with header (column name),but no more data. (10 columns x 4k rows).

Key codes snippet as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(r'/Users/' + username + r'/Documents/working/addf6-5.xlsx', header=0))
df = df.replace('#NUM!', '')

value = chain(reversed(grouplist2), df.values.tolist())
for x in value:
    x[4] = str(x[4])
    x[7] = str(x[7])

conn = sqlite3.connect('veradb.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS f65")
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect('veradb.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS f65 ('offer', 'code', 'desc', 'engine', 'cost', 'supplier', 'remark', 'podate', 'empty', 'border')")
c.executemany("INSERT INTO f65 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", value)
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

More details for explanation:
Cache data is in addf6-5, I fetched new data in grouplist2 (it's a list) and used `chain(reversed(grouplist2), df.values.tolist())`to combine data.

Why used

```
for x in value:
    x[4] = str(x[4])
    x[7] = str(x[7])
```

Because my pycharm report "Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type."&"Error binding parameter 7 - probably unsupported type." So I do STR again though they should be TEXT according to SQLite by default.

I tried to test "value" via

```
for x in value:
    x[4] = str(x[4])
    x[7] = str(x[7])
    print(x)
```

And found they could be printed correctly.Maybe this proved value (lists) was correct?

Some people may doubt if attribute missed in "CREATE TABLE" sentence, I can say Sqlite provided them TEXT by default is no typing and I execute these codes on other files and worked.

Looking forward to your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try manually populating `value` with 10 string literals.  If that doesn't work, you have some other problem.  Also, it is very abnormal to do a create table statement without specifying column types for all columns.  You should probably do that.

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS f65 (offer text, code text, desc text, engine text, cost text,
                          supplier text, remark text, podate text, empty text, border text)'''). Same. Not working.

Comment: And what was the error message from that?

Comment: No error. But no data stored. (only table f65 existed and column name in)

Comment: Did you try 'SELECT count(\*) from f65' after the INSERT and the commit? How many records you have in the table according to the count(\*) ?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. The answer is "0". Frequently I use "DB Browser for SQLite". I could see other table with full data.(f61,f64,etc). In f65, only column name. No data.

Comment: @TimWang: What gives the output of `print(len(value))`?  And if greater `0` the output of `print(len(value[0]))`

Comment: The result of print(len(value[0])) is TypeError: 'itertools.chain' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: Solved.Thanks for tips from @stovfl value = chain(reversed(grouplist2), df.values.tolist()) is itertools.chain. If I add value = list(value), solved.